# Database created from Code first shows in Server Explorer and not in SQL Server Object Explorer

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, visual-studio

Database 'EFCheck' (Created by Entity Framework code first) is showing in Server Explorer and not in SQL Server Object Explorer and I'm not seeing the created database in my SQL Server. Can anyone tell me where I can see the new db in SQL Server ?

[Server Explorer where I see the new EFCheck db created by EF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9OBLB.png)

[SQL Server Object Explorer where I don't see the EFCheck db](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3jGK3.png)

My connection string in Web.Config

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="Db" 
         connectionString="Data Source=ABHI\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=True" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

*DbContext*

```
public class Db : DbContext { 
   public Db() : base("name=Db") { } 
   public virtual DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; set; } 
   public virtual DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; } 
}
```

Comment: can you share the `DbContext` code also ?

Comment: public class Db : DbContext
    {       
        public Db()
            : base("name=Db")
        {
        }

        public virtual DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }
    }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't specify the `Initial Catalog` in your connection string.You have to set the `Initial catalog` as shown below.

```
<add name="Db" 
connectionString="Data Source=ABHI\SQLEXPRESS;
Initial Catalog=Your-Db-Name-Should-Be-Set-Here;
Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

Comment: Thought EF will create a new DB with a name and I don't have to specify one. Can you please elaborate

Comment: Yes,EF creates it.But you cannot see it on your  `SQL Server Object Explorer`.That is the issue.For that you have to specify `Initial Catalog`.

Comment: After adding the initial catalog how do i verify this?

Comment: You have to remove already generated one and need to create new one with above configuration.After that refresh the `SQL Server Object Explorer`.

Comment: After adding the initial catalog it worked. Thanks :)